# excel pivot table - multiple columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table in Excel using the following data:

[image]

The end result I'm trying to come up with (using the pivot) is a summary like this:

[image]

However I can't figure out how to get Excel to count / add / consider all columns.  I can create a pivot for each individual field/column, but can't figure out how to compile the data together.

Comment: I think your concept is impossible to do with Pivot tables.

Comment: Either that or a major bug in Excel :\ Thanks for the effort anyway.  I know I can do this via a MySQL query -- was hoping to simplify this a bit with Excel, but I guess not.

Comment: it's strange enough alright :P Does Pynners answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

Forgive the mac excel in the picture but here is how you can set up a pivot table.

Note though that the row labels will reflect only categories that are in the column you put in the row section

[image]

Comment: @Pyner Thanks, and the key indicator is what you noted in your second sentence -- only what is in the row label will determine what categories / columns are displayed.

That said, the question is if there a way to pivot using multiple rows.  I've read some other articles / forums where it was recommended to create an additional "helper" column to do this.  However I wasn't able to make any sense of it.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure that I follow the concept of a helper column in this scenario. Presumably you create a column that has all of the unique values to be selected, and use that as the row label. That said, I am not sure how you could have it auto update for new categories. If the categories are known ahead of time though, it is more simple to us `countif` formulas instead as you can avoid all the manual refreshing.