# MySQL - grouping data by columns

Tags: mysql, database

As a follow up to my first [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494171/excel-pivot-table-multiple-columns) where I was asking for help manipulating data into an excel pivot table, I'm of the presumption that this can only be done via a database command using unions.  Thus I'm submitting a new question with the same data, but from a MySQL standpoint.

I have the follwoing table:

```
mysql> select * from ilike;
+-----------+------------+----------+
| likebread | likecheese | likemilk |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| girl      | boy        | girl     |
| boy       | girl       | boy      |
| boy       | boy        | boy      |
| boy       | boy        | girl     |
| boy       | boy        | boy      |
| boy       | girl       | boy      |
| girl      | boy        | girl     |
| boy       | girl       | girl     |
| boy       | boy        | girl     |
| girl      | boy        | boy      |
+-----------+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd like count and group the data in the individual columns, so that the end result is a table that shows the counts for boys and girls for each respective column as in:

```
        +-----------+------------+----------+
        | likebread | likecheese | likemilk |
+-------+-------+------------+--------------+
| boys  | 7         | 7          | 5        |
| girls | 3         | 3          | 5        |
+-------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: Can you normalize this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
select g.gender,
       sum(case when likebread=g.gender then 1 end) likebread,
       sum(case when likecheese=g.gender then 1 end) likecheese,
       sum(case when likemilk=g.gender then 1 end) likemilk
from (select 'girl' gender union select 'boy') g
cross join ilike
group by g.gender
```

**Result**

```
| GENDER | LIKEBREAD | LIKECHEESE | LIKEMILK |
----------------------------------------------
|    boy |         7 |          7 |        5 |
|   girl |         3 |          3 |        5 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dcf21/5)

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for your post.  When I try and run this query I'm getting this error:

ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Thoughts? I'm running this on Mac OS X - MySQL version: 5.5.9

Comment: Follow up -- I was able to resolve the collation issue -- I had my database and table set to latin1_swedish_ci.  Thanks for the help on this!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, just wondering why this couldn't be done using count queries.  Obviously didn't work for me, but I'd be interested in the technical understanding of why that wouldn't work.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jaren: You could have used count rather than sum in the above query and it would have worked just as well - there are other ways you could have done it, too, but this seemed the simplest to me.