# Excel pivot table - counting separate columns in one table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

THis is a bit of redux on an old post (link below) but I figure this is worth asking again to see if anyone else might be of assistance. The distinction between this question and the previous one (which wasn't clearly answered) is that there are multiple rows for categories and the values in the rows aren't represented in the columns:

I have this dataset in Excel, linked from a SQL Server view (it's a little wide, you have to scroll right to see all the columns)

```
Diagnosis   Blood 1 Status    Blood 1 Response   Blood 1 Draw    Blood 2 Status    Blood 2 Response  Blood 2 Draw    Blood 3 Status   Blood 3 Response  Blood 3 Draw
Colon        Pre              No response            A           
Colon        Pre              Response               A             Mid              Response            A     
Colon        Pre              No response            A             Mid              No response         A              Post            No response         A
Colon        Mid              Response               A             Mid              Response            A     
Colon        Mid                                     A             Mid                                  A              Post                                A
Colon        Mid              Response               A           
Colon        Post             Response               A             Post             Response            A     
Colon        Post             No response            A                                                  A     
Colon        Post             No response            A             Post             No response         A              Post            No response         A
Pancreas     Pre              No response            A                                                                 
Pancreas     Pre              Response               A             Mid              Response            A                  
Pancreas     Mid              No response            A             Mid              No response         A              Mid             Response            A
Pancreas     Mid              Response               A           
Pancreas     Post                                    A             Post                                 A
```

What I need to do is pivot the data for each set of blood data by diagnosis/blood status/blood treatment status and return the count of Blood Draw. This is simple enough to do for one set, **but I need all three sets on the same table.** I can't figure out a way in Excel to do it and am trying to avoid doing it in SQL or doing separate pivots per set and copying/pasting.

Any ideas? below is what I'm looking for as a final product (copy/paste job to illustrate):

[image]

This is the link to the previous question:  [excel pivot table - multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494171/excel-pivot-table-multiple-columns)

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste error when I was doing the mock final product in Excel. should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems the actual numbers are not particularly important, this just addresses layout. With fields arranged so:

[image: SO25851213 first example]

A PivotTable such as this may be output from the data sample:

[image: SO25851213 second example]

Blanks may be shown as zeros by selecting PivotTable Options..., Layout & Format, For empty cells show: `0`.